# Excel setup and formulae

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to send out tailored checklists to clients.

What I would like to do is have a table on sheet 1 with all of my clients in column A and all the potential paragraphs they need on their checklists in columns B,C,D etc.

Each client would have their own tab (i.e. checklist) and the checklist would be populated based on whether I had put in a tick/X in columns B, C, D etc.

Is this doable? If so where do I start and what formulae are involved?

Thank you in advance.

Liam

Comment: The use of IF() or even drop down lists can work - but it can get very challenging to have the list re-sort without blank areas ... I used large() to get round that once...

Comment: yes this is doable.